# WSO2 Proxy send to ActiveMQ got error JMSSecurityException: User name [null] or password is invalid

Tags: wso2-esb

Tried to create a non-secure WSO2 proxy service to send message to ActiveMQ JMS queue. The proxy service configuration xml file as listed below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="StockQuoteProxy" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable"
  transports="http" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<target>
<inSequence>
  <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
  <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
  <send>
    <endpoint>
      <address trace="disable" uri="jms:/JMSQueueConsumer?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&amp;java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=tcp://127.0.0.1:61616&amp;transport.jms.DestinationType=queue"/>
    </endpoint>
  </send>
</inSequence>
<outSequence/>
<faultSequence/>
```

I also have followed WSO2 document to enable activeMQ Listener and Sender in axis2.xml. 
I have also created a JMSQueueConsumer queue in activeMQ on local host. The activeMQ is

```
up,     tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:61616      :::*                        LISTEN
```

However, when I tried to send message to activeMQ, I got error

```
[PassThroughMessageProcessor-47] ERROR JMSSender Unable to create a JMSMessageSender for : null
javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: User name [null] or password is invalid.
```

and activeMQ shows no activity. Where should I configure the user name and password?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need to set username and password for sender using properties transport.jms.UserName and transport.jms.Password as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="StockQuoteProxy"
       transports="http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED"
                   value="true"
                   scope="axis2"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="jms:/JMSQueueConsumer?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&amp;java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=tcp://127.0.0.1:61616&amp;transport.jms.DestinationType=queue&amp;transport.jms.UserName=admin&amp;transport.jms.Password=secret"
                        trace="disable"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
      <faultSequence/>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```